# Issue in YouTube data transfer in Big query

Tags: google-bigquery

Upto 31st January 2024,I had no issues in getting YouTube revenue data from YouTube data transfer in my big query views, but from 1 Feb the table containing YouTube revenue data are not getting updated, can any one help me in this.